# Mule 3.5 EE default logging not working

Tags: mule

I'm struggling to get the default logging working for a deployed application.

From my understanding, for a Mule app that contains no log4j.properties/xml file the Mule server will generate a log file named (going by the wrapper.conf file) %MULE_BASE%/logs/%MULE_APP%.log.

This isn't happening, instead all the logging is going into mule_ee.log, no app log file is created.

Are there any settings I should be looking at to make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying that with the Bookstore example that comes bundled with Mule ESB, deleting first the log4j.properties included in it and works fine. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Sorry Ale I didn't see your comment. I'll try again when I'm back at work on Monday and let you know - thanks.

Comment: I've tried the Bookstore app, I deployed the example zip with log4j file removed, and build the app source after removing the log4j file, neither have a named logfile created for them. I'm not sure what else to add, I get the same result locally and on a remote dev server.

Comment: Are you starting Mule using bin/mule? Do you have something configured on your conf/wrapper.conf?

Comment: I did initially use the startup.bat and run Mule as a service, I've disabled the service and tried bin/mule but I'm getting the same result. I've just tried a fresh install of Mule and run via bin/Mule, deployed the bookstore app but still no log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in 3.5.0 in windows platform, see [this](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7696). In the next few days 3.5.1 will be released and you can upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Ale, saves banging my head against the wall any longer.